# mount on busybox: invalid argument when trying to mount smb share

Tags: mount, busybox

I am trying to mount a smb share on my embedded Linux running on ARM (3.6.9) with busybox 1.21

```
mount -t cifs //192.168.0.12/mydata /mnt/myData
```

results in an invalid argument error:

```
mount: mounting /192.168.0.12/mydata/ on /mnt/myData failed: Invalid argument
```

CIFS support is definetly installed and the directories exist.
Is there any syntax difference in busybox's mount command?
Thank in advance!

Comment: Can you please give the exact error message? And where is the `user` option mentioned in the question title in your command? Oh, and where do you give the username/password for this share?

Comment: Sorry, I messed up. Wrote the title when I still had a different error message.

Comment: With busybox v1.1.3 this command succeeds: `mount -t cifs //192.168.1.11/Files /mnt/files -o username=windows_user,password=windows_pwd`, so obviously no general problem. Does the mount command with increased verbosity `-vvv` give some more hints?

Comment: Just double checking that CIFS support is installed, does the file `/sbin/mount.cifs` exist?

Answer (score 1):

The clue is in the output:

```
mount: mounting /192.168.0.12/mydata/ on /mnt/myData failed: Invalid argument
```

Shares are not referenced starting with a single `/`.

For CIFS shares you need to use backslashes. You then need to double up these to escape them, otherwise the shell thinks they have a special meaning.

Try:

```
mount -t cifs \\\\192.168.0.12\\mydata /mnt/myData
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to mount CIFS volumes, the `mount` command needs to prepare a bit of extra information for the kernel, which is why you have to use a special `mount.cifs` command for that. The regular `mount` command will automatically defer to that as long as it is installed, so you don't normally see that.

Answer (score 0):

As mpy commented to the original question,

> mount -t cifs //192.168.1.11/Files /mnt/files -o
>   username=windows_user,password=windows_pwd

is doing the job. Just append the -o part to your command.

BusyBox v1.8.1

I also wanted to mention, that on my embedded system there is no mount.cifs available and anyway it works.

Answer (score -1):

Just put some quotes around the directory to escape the slashes. Also handy if there are spaces in directory names.

```
mount -t cifs '//192.168.1.123/Mateo Disk'  /dev/myData -o username=alison,password=monkey
```

Comment: Slash `/` is not a special character for shell. It does not need to be escaped. (Space is a special character.)